# A tough integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

As a physicist of living matter, I've come across this integral in my work : $\int_1^x\frac{\tanh(u)}{u^4} du$. Does anyone have an idea how to compute it ? Mathematica returns nothing of value, and I need more than asymptotics...
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Whats the relationship between $u$ and $x$?

Comment: @John_dydx Isn't _u_ just a dummy variable?

Comment: @John_dydx Yes, u is a dummy variable, and $x \geq 1$.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried Mathematica, ahah. I don't have much knowledge in computing hard primitives. My first integral was something far uglier but I got it down to this by changing variables. It first was something like $\int^x \sqrt{u} \tanh(\sqrt{y/u}) du$ where $y$ is fixed and positive.

Comment: The indefinite integral $\int \frac{\tanh u}{u^4}$ is presumably non-elementary. Otherwise, Mathematica would have found a closed-form expression.

Comment: @Célestin I guess so... But I heard of cases where Mathematica would do worse than clever approaches to some integrals, so I tried my luck

Comment: You could get good results from people on this site with a large improper integral, but you cannot expect anything better than a series solution to a nonelementary general integral such as this

Answer (score 5):

I hope this estimation is good enough for you.

Remarking that $\tanh(u)=\sinh(u)/\cosh(u)$, and $\cosh'(u)=\sinh(u)$, one can integrate by parts obtaining
\begin{align}\int_1^x u^{-4}\tanh(u)du&=\left[u^{-4}\ln\cosh(u)\right]_{1}^{x}+\frac{1}{5}\int_{1}^x u^{-5}\ln\cosh(u)du=\\
&=\frac{\ln\cosh(x)}{x^4}-\ln\cosh(1)+\frac{1}{5}\int_{1}^x u^{-5}\ln\cosh(u)du.\end{align}

$1\le\cosh(u)=\frac{e^u+e^{-u}}{2}\le e^u$ for $u\ge1$, that is $0\le\ln\cosh(u)\le u$ for $u\ge1$.

It follows that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{20}(1-x^{-4})\le\int_1^x u^{-4}\tanh(u)du-\frac{\ln\cosh(x)}{x^4}+\ln\cosh(1)\le\frac{1}{15}(1-x^{-3}).
\end{align}

Again, if you don't like having $\ln\cosh(x)$, you can use the same estimation as above and obtain
\begin{align}
-\ln\cosh(1)+\frac{1}{20}(1-x^{-4})\le\int_1^x u^{-4}\tanh(u)du\le x^{-3}-\ln\cosh(1)+\frac{1}{15}(1-x^{-3}).
\end{align}

**EDIT:** I remarked my estimation have been really sloppy, since I could have use this estimation instead
\begin{align}
\frac{e^{u}}{2}\le\cosh(u)=\frac{e^u+e^{-u}}{2}\le e^u \Rightarrow u-\ln2\le\ln\cosh(u)\le u,\ \text{for}\ u\ge1.
\end{align}

It follows
\begin{align}
F(x)-\frac{\ln(2)}{20}(1-x^{-4})\le\int_1^x u^{-4}\tanh(u)du\le F(x).
\end{align}
where $F(x)=\frac{\ln\cosh(x)}{x^4}-\ln\cosh(1)+\frac{1}{15}(1-x^{-3}).$

Comment: Thanks ! Sadly it won't help much for my problem. Excuse me if I'm mistaken but I think you've forgotten the $x=1$ boundary term after integrating by parts, but no biggie.

Comment: No, simply $\ln\cosh(1)=\ln(1)=0$. In any case, you can try integrate by parts in the opposite direction, by using the property of hyperbolic functions and by estimating the logarithm which appears at the end.

It is not difficult, but there are too much counts for me to write them down on latex.

Comment: Well but $\cosh(1) \neq 1$ right ?

Comment: you are right, my bad, i'll correct